# Athena query with joins

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, join, left-join, amazon-athena

I am trying to run query on Athena which is not behaving as expected:

```
select distinct aw.year, aw.month, aw.day
  from aw
  left join f on aw.c1= f.c1
             and aw.c2 = f.c2
             and aw.c3 = f.c3
             and aw.year = '2022'
             and aw.month = '2'
             and aw.day = '5'
```

I am expecting this query to return 2022, 2, 5 but it is returning several other values of year, month and day. The below query works fine and returns only 2022, 2, 5.

```
select distinct aw.year, aw.month, aw.day
  from aw
  join f on aw.c1= f.c1
        and aw.c2 = f.c2
        and aw.c3 = f.c3
        and aw.year = '2022'
        and aw.month = '2'
        and aw.day = '5'
```

The problem is when I add left join but I am also adding the filer of required year, month and day. I am doing something wrong logically here?

Comment: share sample data and expected output

Comment: well data is so huge. I am worried about what's wrong logically here?

Comment: `left join` will return all values from the left part of the join. If `join` does what is needed - why do you need a left one?

Comment: I need left join. But you see I am doing the filter on the columns of left table (aw) like `aw.year = '2022' and aw.month = '2' and aw.day = '5'`. But it still returns all the rows from left table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be confusing conditions within an `ON` with conditions in a `WHERE`.

Your `left join` query returned rows where `aw` had other values because you were providing conditions for how to **join** the rows between tables. It does not limit the rows from the 'left' table.

If you only want to return rows where the LEFT table (`aw`) date matches `2022-02-05`, then you should put those conditions in a `WHERE`:

```sql
select distinct aw.year, aw.month, aw.day
  from aw
  left join f on aw.c1 = f.c1
             and aw.c2 = f.c2
             and aw.c3 = f.c3
  where aw.year = '2022'
    and aw.month = '2'
    and aw.day = '5'
```

Comment: Why does it work with inner join (join) and not with left join?

Comment: Your `left join` query is saying: "Return every row from `aw`, and try to join those rows to `f` where these conditions are true". My code (above) says: "Return only the rows from `aw` that are for `2022-02-05`, and try to join those rows to `f` where these conditions are true".